# php - Error when trying to subtract from non-object

Tags: php, arrays

I have two objects, `$opening_time` and `$closing_time`, in a `foreach` loop which iterates through database names.

Both objects contain opening and closing times for each database. I'm trying to subtract the opening times from the closing times, but when there’s more of one than the other, I get a notice error that says:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Is there a way to skip times that don’t have a match to subtract from? The iterator I’ve been  using to perform the subtraction has been either the count of opening times or the count of closing times, so whichever I use, if there’s more of the other then I get an error.

Example $closing_time contents:

```
FMServer_Sample

stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 14:42:51
)
stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 13:24:36
)

iCDS

stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 16:34:59
)
stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 12:03:15
)
stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 08:12:49
)
```

PHP

```
$result = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < count($closing_time); $x++) {
    if ($closing_time != "" && $opening_time != "") {
         $result += (strtotime($closing_time[$x]->log_time) - strtotime($opening_time[$x]->log_time));
         }
     }

print "<pre>";
print_r($result);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: `for ($x = 0; $x < count($closing_time) && $x < count($opening_time); $x++)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you so much. I did not know it was possible to use a logical operator like that in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
if ($closing_time != "" && $opening_time != "") {
```

Maybe it should be changed to use proper `isset()` and `!empty()` logic like this:

```
if ((isset($closing_time) && !empty($closing_time))
 && (isset($opening_time) && !empty($opening_time))) {
```